# Batch file that runs cmd.exe, a command, and then stays open at prompt

Tags: batch, command-line

I would like to make a batch file that:

1. Opens cmd.exe
2. Within that Command Prompt runs `net use` to display mapped share paths
3. Leaves the window open so that I can run additional commands if I wish to

How can I do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Put in your batch file

```
start cmd.exe /k "net use"
```

From `cmd /?`

> Starts a new instance of the Windows
>   XP command interpreter
>
> CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON |
>   /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON |
>   /V:OFF]
>       [[/S] [/C | /K] string]
>
> /C      Carries out the command
>   specified by string and then
>   terminates
>   /K      Carries out the
>   command specified by string but
>   remains

Comment: I am not entirely sure why, but the batch file with that first line opened about 100 windows...

Comment: Oh, I know why, I named my batch file "net use.bat", and therefore cmd.exe tried to run "net use" and found the batch file first since it was the closest, therefore it was recursively running the batch file.  LOL :()

Comment: @aaronls That is hilarious:)

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific.  Perhaps you should use `net.exe use` next time... proof you can never assume anything.

Comment: davr's "hilarious" batch file quickly brought my Win 7 machine to a halt. It wouldn't respond to Ctrl+Shift+Esc, Ctrl+Alt+Delete, Ctrl+Break etc. Make sure your documents are saved first.

Comment: If this ever does happen, you can right click on cmd.exe in Task Manager's Processes tab and click "End Process Tree". It will only end the ancestors of the one you click on though, not the descendants, so you may have to do this several times.

Comment: Or even better: open a new Command Prompt and type, *without quotes*: "Tskill cmd" - this will close all Command Prompt windows. https://commandwindows.com/taskkill.htm

Comment: i swapped the 'start' with 'call' command and the command executed in the same window. This was more preferred way for me.