# How do I stop the command window from automatically closing at the end?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch file that runs cmd.exe, a command, and then stays open at prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/106848/batch-file-that-runs-cmd-exe-a-command-and-then-stays-open-at-prompt)

I have a set of environmental variables that I have to run before I can run other operations. I have a batch file for these but when I run the batch file it closes at the end. Is there something I can add so it will not close so I can continue to run other operations in the command prompt without writing them into the batch file script itself?

I eventually would like to have a batch file for each operation but I have a lot of different operations I need to run. So for now this will help to avoid the manual work of opening the batch file and copying and pasting the variables into a new command prompt window every time I go to run a new operation.

Comment: How are you opening the command-prompt/running the batch-file. There are at least three ways that this can be solved depending on your circumstances.

Comment: I am running the batch file from windows explorer window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some environment variables set every time that you use the command-prompt, then there are three ways that you can do so:

- Create the environment variables [at the system level](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519), then they will always be available at the command-prompt. You can do this for either a user or the the whole system.
- Instead of running the batch file directly, create a shortcut to the command-interpreter, passing it the batch-file as an argument, and using the `/k` switch to keep it open after running:

  ```
  %comspec% /k c:\stuff\setenvs.bat
  ```
- You can set the `Autorun` key to automatically run a command whenever you open a command-prompt. Again, you can set it for just a user or the whole system:

  ```
  REGEDIT4
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
  "Autorun"="c:\stuff\setenvs.bat"
  ```

Comment: Awesome, I got the /K switch working. Thank you so much. You just made my life soo much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Run command prompt with the `/K` switch. This prevents it from closing after the `.bat` has run

---

*Source*: http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html